# How to convet gstreamer command code to C code?

Tags: audio, video, debian, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

The command is:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=/home/pi/Videos/watch.mp4 ! qtdemux name=demux \
demux.audio_0 ! queue ! decodebin ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! autoaudiosink \
demux.video_0 ! queue ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! videoscale ! video/x-raw,width=800,height=480 ! avenc_bmp ! fakesink
```

It's a little difficult for me to link them together because both 'qtdemux' and 'decodebin' are used in this example.

I have tried with 'tee', but it's obviously slow.

Could anyone give me some help?Thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gstreamer-1.0/gst/gst.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct {
    GstElement *pipeline;
    GstElement *filesrc;
    GstElement *qtdemux;
    /* Video */
    struct{
        GstElement *queue;
        GstElement *decode;
        GstElement *convert;
        GstElement *scale;
        GstElement *capsfilter;
        GstElement *enc_bmp;
        GstElement *fakesink;
    }video;
    /* Audio */
    struct{
        GstElement *queue;
        GstElement *decode;
        GstElement *convert;
        GstElement *resample;
        GstElement *sink;
    }audio;
} gstreamer_t;

static void pad_added_handler (GstElement *src, GstPad *pad, gstreamer_t* data)
{
    GstCaps *caps;
    GstStructure *pad_sct;
    const gchar *name;

    caps = gst_pad_get_current_caps(pad);
    pad_sct = gst_caps_get_structure( caps, 0 );
    name = gst_structure_get_name(pad_sct);

    printf( "src name = %s\r\n", gst_element_get_name(src) );
    printf( "pad name = %s\r\n", name);
    printf( "Received new pad '%s' from '%s'.\r\n", GST_PAD_NAME (pad), GST_ELEMENT_NAME (src));

    GstPad *sinkpad = NULL;
    if(g_str_has_prefix (name, "video/x-h264")) {
        sinkpad = gst_element_get_static_pad(data->video.queue, "sink");
        if(!gst_pad_link(pad, sinkpad) != GST_PAD_LINK_OK )
            printf("not link !!\n\n"); 
        gst_object_unref (sinkpad);
    }else if(g_str_has_prefix( name, "audio/mpeg")){
        sinkpad = gst_element_get_static_pad ( data->audio.queue, "sink");
        if(gst_pad_link( pad, sinkpad) != GST_PAD_LINK_OK )
            printf("not link !!\n\n"); 
        gst_object_unref (sinkpad);
    }
    else
        printf("Another Pad: %s.\r\n", name);

    gst_caps_unref (caps);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    gstreamer_t gstreamer;
    GstBus *bus;
    GstMessage *msg;
    GstStateChangeReturn ret;
    gboolean terminate = FALSE;

    /* Initialize GStreamer */
    gst_init (&argc, &argv);

    /* Create the elements */
    gstreamer.filesrc = gst_element_factory_make ("filesrc", "filesrc");
    g_object_set (gstreamer.filesrc, "location", "../../Videos/watch.mp4", NULL);
    gstreamer.qtdemux = gst_element_factory_make ("qtdemux", "qtdemux");

    /* Video */
    gstreamer.video.queue = gst_element_factory_make("queue", "video");
    gstreamer.video.decode = gst_element_factory_make ("decodebin", "decodebin");
    gstreamer.video.convert = gst_element_factory_make ("videoconvert", "videoconvert");
    gstreamer.video.scale = gst_element_factory_make ("videoscale", "videoscale");
    gstreamer.video.capsfilter = gst_element_factory_make ("capsfilter", "capsfilter");
    GstCaps *Caps = gst_caps_from_string("video/x-raw,width=800,height=480");
    g_object_set(G_OBJECT(gstreamer.video.capsfilter), "caps", Caps, NULL);
    gst_caps_unref(Caps);
    gstreamer.video.enc_bmp = gst_element_factory_make ("avenc_bmp", "avenc_bmp");

    gstreamer.video.fakesink = gst_element_factory_make ("fakesink", "fakesink");
    g_object_set (gstreamer.video.fakesink, "sync", true, NULL);

    /* Audio */
    gstreamer.audio.queue = gst_element_factory_make("queue", "queue_audio");
    gstreamer.audio.decode = gst_element_factory_make("decodebin", "decodebin");
    gstreamer.audio.convert = gst_element_factory_make("audioconvert", "audioconvert");
    gstreamer.audio.resample = gst_element_factory_make("audioresample", "audioresample");
    gstreamer.audio.sink = gst_element_factory_make("autoaudiosink", "autoaudiosink");

    /* Create the empty pipeline */
    gstreamer.pipeline = gst_pipeline_new ("gstreamer-pipeline");

    if (!gstreamer.pipeline || !gstreamer.filesrc || !gstreamer.qtdemux || 
        !gstreamer.video.queue || !gstreamer.video.decode || !gstreamer.video.convert || !gstreamer.video.scale || !gstreamer.video.capsfilter || !gstreamer.video.enc_bmp || !gstreamer.video.fakesink||
        !gstreamer.audio.queue || !gstreamer.audio.decode || !gstreamer.audio.convert || !gstreamer.audio.resample ||!gstreamer.audio.sink) 
    {
        g_printerr ("Not all elements could be created.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    /* Build the pipeline. Note that we are NOT linking the source at this
    * point. We will do it later. */
    gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (gstreamer.pipeline), gstreamer.filesrc, gstreamer.qtdemux,
                        gstreamer.video.queue, gstreamer.video.decode, gstreamer.video.convert, gstreamer.video.scale, gstreamer.video.capsfilter, gstreamer.video.enc_bmp, gstreamer.video.fakesink, 
                        gstreamer.audio.queue, gstreamer.audio.decode, gstreamer.audio.convert, gstreamer.audio.resample, gstreamer.audio.sink, NULL);
    
    if (!gst_element_link (gstreamer.filesrc, gstreamer.qtdemux)) {
        g_printerr ("Elements filesrc and qtdemux could not be linked.\n");
        gst_object_unref (gstreamer.pipeline);
        return -1;
    }

    if (!gst_element_link_many (gstreamer.video.convert, gstreamer.video.scale, gstreamer.video.capsfilter, gstreamer.video.enc_bmp, gstreamer.video.fakesink, NULL)) {
        g_printerr ("Video elements could not be linked.\n");
        gst_object_unref (gstreamer.pipeline);
        return -1;
    }

    if (!gst_element_link_many (gstreamer.audio.convert, gstreamer.audio.resample, gstreamer.audio.sink, NULL)) {
        g_printerr ("Audio elements could not be linked.\n");
        gst_object_unref (gstreamer.pipeline);
        return -1;
    }

    g_signal_connect (gstreamer.qtdemux, "pad-added", G_CALLBACK (pad_added_handler), &gstreamer);

    /* Start playing */
    ret = gst_element_set_state (gstreamer.pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
    if (ret == GST_STATE_CHANGE_FAILURE) {
        g_printerr ("Unable to set the pipeline to the playing state.\n");
        gst_object_unref (gstreamer.pipeline);
        return -1;
    }

    /* Listen to the bus */
    bus = gst_element_get_bus (gstreamer.pipeline);
    do {
        msg = gst_bus_timed_pop_filtered (bus, GST_CLOCK_TIME_NONE,
            GST_MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGED | GST_MESSAGE_ERROR | GST_MESSAGE_EOS);

        /* Parse message */
        if (msg != NULL) {
        GError *err;
        gchar *debug_info;

        switch (GST_MESSAGE_TYPE (msg)) {
            case GST_MESSAGE_ERROR:
                gst_message_parse_error (msg, &err, &debug_info);
                g_printerr ("Error received from element %s: %s\n", GST_OBJECT_NAME (msg->src), err->message);
                g_printerr ("Debugging information: %s\n", debug_info ? debug_info : "none");
                g_clear_error (&err);
                g_free (debug_info);
                terminate = TRUE;
            break;
            
            case GST_MESSAGE_EOS:
                g_print ("\nEnd-Of-Stream reached.\n");
                terminate = TRUE;
            break;
            
            case GST_MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGED:
                /* We are only interested in state-changed messages from the pipeline */
                if (GST_MESSAGE_SRC (msg) == GST_OBJECT (gstreamer.pipeline)) {
                    GstState old_state, new_state, pending_state;
                    gst_message_parse_state_changed (msg, &old_state, &new_state, &pending_state);
                    g_print ("Pipeline state changed from %s to %s:\n",
                        gst_element_state_get_name (old_state), gst_element_state_get_name (new_state));
                }
            break;
        break;
            default:
            /* We should not reach here */
            g_printerr ("Unexpected message received.\n");
            break;
        }
        gst_message_unref (msg);
        }
    } while (!terminate);

    /* Free resources */
    gst_object_unref (bus);
    gst_element_set_state (gstreamer.pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
    gst_object_unref (gstreamer.pipeline);

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

> (stream:5337): GStreamer-WARNING **: 02:28:38.279: Name 'decodebin' is not unique in bin 'gstreamer-pipeline', not adding
> Pipeline state changed from NULL to READY:
> src name = qtdemux
> pad name = video/x-h264
> Received new pad 'video_0' from 'qtdemux'.
> not link !!
>
> src name = qtdemux
> pad name = audio/mpeg
> Received new pad 'audio_0' from 'qtdemux'.
> Error received from element qtdemux: Internal data stream error.
> Debugging information: ../gst/isomp4/qtdemux.c(6545): gst_qtdemux_loop (): /GstPipeline:gstreamer-pipeline/GstQTDemux:qtdemux:
> streaming stopped, reason not-linked (-1)

I dont't know how to link the video and audio.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're facing is with respect to decodebin.
One single pipeline cannot contain two elements that have the same name.

In your case,

```
 gstreamer.video.decode = gst_element_factory_make ("decodebin", "decodebin");
```

and

```
gstreamer.audio.decode = gst_element_factory_make("decodebin", "decodebin");
```

Have the same names set to `decodebin`
Thats why one of the decodebins are not even being added to the pipeline.
You can change it to something else. For example

```
gstreamer.audio.decode = gst_element_factory_make("decodebin", "decodebin-audio");
```

and

```
gstreamer.video.decode = gst_element_factory_make("decodebin", "decodebin-video");
```

This rule applies to any parent element that is directly added to your pipeline.